Cloud-init Wi-Fi won't connect after Ubuntu release upgrade
I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu Server 22.04 to 24.04. I remember being asked if I wanted to keep my cloud-init configuration or reset it.
I chose poorly...
After deciding to reset the configuration, Wi-Fi stopped working and I am stuck for some days now trying to get it back to work. Here's what I have tried so far:

Generated the hashed passwords for the access points with wpa_passphrase <SSID> <password>;
Updated /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml (see below for its configuration);
Ran sudo netplan generate, sudo netplan apply and rebooted the device, only to find out it does not connect through Wi-Fi;
Tried connecting through Ethernet, it works, so the problem is only present for Wi-Fi;

To cross out the possibility of a typo on my side, I have double and triple checked that I am not inserting the wrong SSID or password in wpa_passphrase, and since the password contains special characters, I'm wrapping them around single quotes (e.g., wpa_passphrase my_ssid 'p@$$w0rd').


I have also tried the solution proposed here, disabling network config and moving the cloud-init YAML to /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml, to no avail as well.

Below is the configuration in /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:
network:
  version: 2
  rendered: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      optional: true
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      access-points:
        "ssid_1":
          auth:
            key-management: "psk"
            password: "somepassword"
        "ssid_2":
          auth:
            key-management: "psk"
            password: "someotherpassword"

Output for sudo netplan --debug generate:
DEBUG:command generate: running ['/usr/libexec/netplan/generate']
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.750: starting new process pass
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.750: wlan0: adding wifi AP 'ssid_1'
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.750: wlan0: adding wifi AP 'ssid_2'
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.750: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.750: wlan0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.750: Configuration is valid
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.750: eth0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.750: Configuration is valid
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.753: Generating output files..
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.754: Open vSwitch: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.754: NetworkManager: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.754: Creating wpa_supplicant config
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.754: wlan0: Creating wpa_supplicant configuration file run/netplan/wpa-wlan0.conf
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.754: Creating wpa_supplicant unit /run/systemd/system/netplan-wpa-wlan0.service
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.772: Creating wpa_supplicant service enablement link /run/systemd/system/systemd-network.sevice.wants/netplan-wpa-wlan0.service
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.773: Open vSwitch: definition wlan0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:3574): DEBUG: 11:02:34.773: NetworkManager: definition wlan0 is not for us (backend 1)

Output for sudo netplan --debug apply:
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.284: starting new processing pass
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.285: wlan0: adding wifi AP 'ssid_1'
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.285: wlan0: adding wifi AP 'ssid_2'
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.285: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.285: wlan0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.285: Configuration is valid
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.285: eth0: setting default backend to 1
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.285: Configuration is valid
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.287: Generating output files..
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.287: Open vSwitch: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.287: NetworkManager: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.287: Creating wpa_supplicant config
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.287: wlan0: Creating wpa_supplicant configuration file run/netplan/wpa-wlan0.conf
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.288: Creating wpa_supplicant unit /run/systemd/system/netplan-wpa-wlan0.service
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.303: Creating wpa_supplicant service enablement link /run/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.wants/netplan-wpa-wlan0.service
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.304: Open vSwitch: definition wlan0 is not for us (backend 1)
** (generate:4090): DEBUG: 11:11:21.304: NetworkManager: definition wlan0 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG:netplan generated networkd configuration changed, rloading networkd
DEBUG:Cannot call Open vSwitch: Cannot apply OVS cleanup: ovsdb-server.service is 'not-found'.
DEBUG:no netplan generated NM configuration exists
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:22.850: starting new processing pass
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:22.850: wlan0: adding wifi AP 'ssid_1'
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:22.850: wlan0: adding wifi AP 'ssid_2'
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:22.850: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:22.850: wlan0: setting default backend to 1
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:22.850: Configuration is valid
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:22.850: eth0: setting default backend to 1
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:22.850: Configuration is valid
DEBUG:Merged config:
b''
DEBUG:Link changes: {}
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for lo
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for eth0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for wlan0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for br-80d4bffdaa75
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for br-bc3170df0d76
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for docker0
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for br-0ef74bacdfe7
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for br-2325d6d5e94d
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for br-4ae99280b2fc
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for br-603e3680c9f6
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for br-732ea9bdd972
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for br-2854576e21a1
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for br-306b180c54fe
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for br-a072a3e05d65
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for veth51c8df9
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vethf75fdc5
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vetha4f08ef
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for veth19e6d5d
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vethce29dc8
DEBUG:netplan triggering .link rules for vethd949d9b
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:24.424: starting new processing pass
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:24.424: wlan0: adding wifi AP 'ssid_1'
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:24.424: wlan0: adding wifi AP 'ssid_2'
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:24.424: We have some netdefs, pass them through a final round of validation
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:24.424: wlan0: setting default backend to 1
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:24.424: Configuration is valid
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:24.424: eth0: setting default backend to 1
** (process:4089): DEBUG: 11:11:24.424: Configuration is valid

Any clues as to what could be causing only the Wi-Fi to not work? Many thanks in advance!

Edits
sudo lshw -C network output:
*-interface:0
    description: Wireless interface
    product: 43430
    vendor: Broadcom
    physical id: 1
    bus info: mmc@1:0001:1
    logical name: mmc1:0001:1
    logical name: wlan0
    serial: e4:5f:01:d4:ca:c9
    capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.45.234 firmware=01-996384e2 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE802.11
*-network
    description: Ethernet interface
    physical id: b
    logical name: eth0
    serial: e4:5f:01:d4:ca:c8
    size: 1Gbit/s
    capacity: 1Gbit/s
    capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=bcmgenet driverversion=6.8.0-1012-raspi duplex=full ip=192.168.50.53 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s


I am unsure if there is a supported upgrade path between ARM versions of 22.04 to 24.04. Can you try flashing a fresh copy of 24.04?

Can you run the following command and append the results to you question. 'lshw -C network'

@ArchismanPanigrahi, that would be my last resort, as I would end up either backing up the data on my /home folder (which I still haven't set up) or disposing of it altogether. But it's on the radar in case anything else fails :|

@david, there you go! :)

Thanks. Can you now run the following command and append the results to you question. 'nmcli d'  'nmcli r wifi on' 'nmcli d wifi list'

Installing a similar Wifi (Broadcom BCM4352), take a look at the answer at this location: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1528734/installed-ubuntu-24-04-01-on-dell-xps-13-9343-laptop-wifi-not-working

I had the same issue after upgrading Raspberry Pi 4 from Ubuntu Core 22 to Ubuntu Core 24.
When I checked the logs with journalctl -xeu netplan-wpa-wlan0, I saw this:
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan

And what helped for me was to set a regulatory domain for the wifi driver:
sudo cat /etc/modprobe.d/cfg80211.conf 
options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom=CZ

