Installed Ubuntu 24.04.01 on Dell XPS 13 9343 laptop, Wifi not working
new linux user here. I am not able to find wifi on Dell XPS 13 9343 laptop connected to internet via USB tethering. Wireless card - Broadcom BCM4352 802.11ac Dual Band (14e4:43b1) rev 03. I tried to install bcmwl-kernel-source and firmware-b43-installer but getting error unable to locate package for both commands.
Please help!

Thanks for the response mchid. So I tried everything you mentioned but I still got error that is unable to locate the package for both kernel source and firmware installer.
Another thing I could not find my laptop in the list supported by LVFS.  Does it mean anything for wifi issue? Another thing is I checked in Additional Drivers on Software & Updates, it shows -
Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries: BCM4352 802.11ac Dual Band Wireless Network Adapter
This device is using an alternative driver.
○ Using dkms source for the Broadcom STA Wireless driver from broadcom-sta-dkms (proprietary)

When I tried to Apply changes by selecting the driver in Additional Drivers, it does nothing. I just shows that This device is using an alternative driver.

Please post the output of apt that shows the full error (edit your question and then copy and paste the output, and then use your cursor to select the pasted output and then press CTRL+K to format the selected text as code before saving the changes). This will help us determine the issue. Thanks.

Also, what does sudo modprobe wl return? Does this fix the issue?

Wifi finally works!
Thank you for your support!
I think the issue was secure boot. I disabled the secure boot and then was able to install the bcmwl kernel package.

These packages are provided by the restricted and multiverse repositories. These repositories should be enabled by default.
First, run sudo apt update before trying to install packages:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source firmware-b43-installer

If you still cannot locate the packages, then you need to enable the restricted and multiverse repositories:
sudo add-apt-repository restricted multiverse

Then, install the packages:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bcmwl-kernel-source firmware-b43-installer

Also and unless you have a reason to have the universe repository disabled, you should probably make sure the universe repository is enabled as well to prevent similar issues in the future:
sudo add-apt-repository universe


To explain further, the sudo apt update command updates your list of available packages. This command essentially checks to see if updates are available by comparing the list of available packages on your computer to the most recent list of packages available from the repositories.
When you first install Ubuntu, a complete list of available packages may not exist on your computer.
It should be noted however, that this command does not update any software. As explained, the update command only updates the list of available packages. To actually update the software on your system, you must also run sudo apt upgrade or sudo apt full-upgrade after you run sudo apt update like in the following example:
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade

or
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade

For most users, sudo apt full-upgrade is the best option. However, if this is a production computer, it may be best to run sudo apt upgrade instead as this may hold back some updates that you may want to hold off on until whatever project you're working on is finished.
It is recommended to do this daily to avoid issues.

UPDATE:
Finally, try enabling the kernel module:
sudo modprobe wl

and disable secure boot.

What helped me with Ubuntu 24.10 is installing broadcom-sta-dkms:
sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms
reboot

Before that, no Wi-Fi adapter was even visible, so I used an external Wi-Fi dongle to connect to the Internet.
